# Flutter setState function doesn't work when used to change class member

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate, stateful

i have the following codes,

```dart
class mWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  mWidget({super.key, required this.text});
  String text;

  @override
  State<mWidget> createState() => _mWidgetState();
}

class _mWidgetState extends State<mWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text(widget.text),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my custom widget,

```dart
class _MainState extends State<Main> {
  var n = mWidget(text: "Hi");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          n,
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                n.text = "Hello";
              });
            },
            child: Text("Click me"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the code in the main.dart file.

The problem is that pressing the button doesn't change the output on the screen unless a hot reload even though I am calling the setState function.

I wonder why is that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a couple of mistakes in this!

In your code, you made a widget named `mWidget` and created an instance of it, it is not the right approach to access any widget using an instance, as state of instances cannot be updated.

You are using the state of `mWidget` outside of its scope, where it is not accessible.

You can use keys to achieve what you want. (It is not advisable to use this for large-scale project)

Here is a small code which can help you to achieve the functionality you want.

```dart
class mWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  mWidget({Key? key, required this.text}) : super(key: key);
  String text;

  @override
  State<mWidget> createState() => _mWidgetState();
}

class _mWidgetState extends State<mWidget> {
  String text = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    text = widget.text;
    super.initState();
  }

  void updateValue(String newData) {
    setState(() {
      text = newData;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text(text),
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
class _Main extends StatefulWidget {
  const _Main({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<_Main> createState() => _MainState();
}

class _MainState extends State<_Main> {
  GlobalKey<_mWidgetState> _mWidgetStateKey = GlobalKey(); // This is the key declaration of _mWidgetState type

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          mWidget(text: "Hi", key: _mWidgetStateKey),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () =>
                _mWidgetStateKey.currentState!.updateValue("Hello"), // Calling the method of _mWidgetState class.
            child: Text("Click me"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reinitialize the `n` on easy approach like

```dart
   n = mWidget(text: "Hello");
```

Or use state-management property like riverpod/bloc. callback method may also help. I am using ValueNotifier, you dont need to make theses statefulWidget

```dart
class Main extends StatefulWidget {
  const Main({super.key});

  @override
  State<Main> createState() => _MainState();
}

class _MainState extends State<Main> {
  final ValueNotifier textNotifier = ValueNotifier('Hi');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          mWidget(text: textNotifier),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                textNotifier.value = "Hello";
              });
            },
            child: Text("Click me"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class mWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  mWidget({super.key, required this.text});
  ValueNotifier text;

  @override
  State<mWidget> createState() => _mWidgetState();
}

class _mWidgetState extends State<mWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
        child: ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: widget.text,
      builder: (context, value, child) => Text(value),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! But do you know why my way doesn't work? I'd like to know more about how flutter works.

Comment: It will be hard for me to explain, let's think this way.  The `_mWidgetState` using state, and we need to update state instead of `mWidget` . Next thing comes using Key, which might solve your need. But it is a child , you can just pass the value, and it will update based on passed data. you can also directly pass  `Hi` string from `Main`